# Where is "startx" called?

Tags: command-line, scripts, xorg

I know X11 will start through `startx`. `startx` is located in `/usr/bin/startx`. So where is the first call to `startx`? 
I want to know exactly which script is running `startx`.

Comment: Why should `startx` be called? You could run `X` manually.

Comment: @muru I am trying to use `X` via `startx`. I am looking for the part where I call `startx` on Ubuntu.

Comment: Why? How? If you're already using `startx`, what do you mean you're looking for the part you're calling startx?

Comment: @muru I am just curious... I found something related at 
 https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xinit#Autostart_X_at_login`... thank you...

Comment: What OS are you on ?   16.04 uses lightdm instead of startx ... of course you can stop lightdm then launch X using starx ... let us know then we can proceed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**StartX** is a script provided in the X11 apps for a user to convenient start an X11 GUI.  StartX is one of many tools that are available for a user to use.  It starts the X11 with a number of preset configurations and starts some default applications.  If you run the bars "X" command by itself, you'd just have a bare X window with no desktop and nothing running.  You'd have to manually start anything you want running.

In Ubuntu the Lightdm does what Startx does.  It provides an X11 login screen and logs that use into that screen starting up a number of default applications at that includes Unity and other friendly and familiar environment features such as the Navigation Side bar and Desktop.

If you disabled Lightdm, you'd the computer boot to the console.  If you didn't have a graphical environment you could then run the StartX to start one, or run a command to start the Lightdm service to give you a login prompt, which will give you a substantially more friendly environment that the bare StartX.

The command to start the Lightdm service is:

```
$ sudo systemctl start lightdm
```

**More specific to your question of where is the call to StartX.**  There isn't one.  Both StartX and Lightdm starts the X11 server.  They are two different methods of starting the server and are independent of each other.

**If you installed the Ubuntu Server distribution**, X11 would not be installed by default.  It would boot to a login console prompt.  That is where the concern for starting an X environment would be important.  In that case you would could install the X environment by installing **ubuntu-desktop**.  Then you could choose between the to methods described above for starting and X environment.

Comment: Thank you for a detailed description. I noticed that lightdm started in `/etc/init/lightdm.conf`.